# iOS App Memory Differs in Debug and Adhoc(Distribution)

Tags: ios, debugging, memory, distribution, adhoc

My app seems to run pretty flawlessly in Debug. The memory footprint seems reasonable, but for whatever reason when I run an Adhoc version of the game the memory footprint increases dramatically.

Here are shots of what I am seeing in instruments:

Debug:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsjZ2.png

Adhoc:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYlcr.png

I noticed four 4MB allocations in the object list on the Adhoc build that are not there in debug. Is this something special that happens with Adhoc builds? I was disconnected from the debugger for both runs.

This memory increase is causing the application to crash very frequently on devices with only 256 MBs of Memory. Is there anything I could do to remedy this or is it an iOS thing that just happens? I don't think we have any differences in build settings that would bloat the application that much and we don't do any special allocations for Adhoc builds that I know of.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!